# Por que GROUP BY não funciona com MySQL nesse caso?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou usando a linguagem MySQL e estou tentando agrupar uma tabela de profissões com o `GROUP BY` através da consulta abaixo.

```
SELECT name, occupation FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY occupation;
```

Mas recebo esse erro ao tentar agrupar as profissões.

> ERROR 1055 (42000) at line 2: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'run_bcxfn77ibag.OCCUPATIONS.Name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

A tabela é bem simples e possui esse formato

[image: Tabela]

A tabela possui as colunas `name` e `occupation`.

Eu entendi que o erro diz algo sobre o registro está em formado de lista.

Porém ao fazer uma breve consulta das profissões, ele me retorna isso:

[image: Resultado]

Por que isso acontece?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O exemplo não é muito bom porque ele não é conceitualmente adequado para agrupar.

Você quer que mostre só uma vez cada ocupação. Até aí tudo bem, normal. Quer que mostre o nome de alguém que tem esta ocupação. Mas tem várias pessoas, o que fazer com esses nomes diferentes? Mostra só o primeiro? Isso é uma informação útil? Duvido. Então a consulta não faz sentido.

O tratamento padrão é considerar isso um erro. Só pode selecionar colunas que estejam na definição do agrupamento, aí realmente todas informações a serem mostradas só existirão uma vez. Ou pode usar uma [função de agregação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) na coluna, assim a função combina os vários resultados em um só e permite apresentar no agrupamento.

Uma das funções de agregação mais usadas é o [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) que soma todos os valores. Em uma coluna de caracteres não dá para isto, o mais provável é que queira para contar quantas pessoas tem no grupo ([`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)). Se não quer agregar nada tem que tirar a coluna `name` da consulta.

Até tem como desligar esta restrição no MySQL. Mas nem é o caso já que trará resultados errados uma vez que o conceito está errado.

Uma forma de pegar algum valor é com [`ANY_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value), mas desaconselho pelos motivos já citados.

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É verdade, quando fiz a pergunta não notei que ela havia perdido o sentido, isso aconteceu porque a questão pede que os nomes sejam mostrados, mas esqueci de mencionar que poderia ser em consultas distintas. thank so much.

Comment: @Maniero você consegue me ajudar com esse erro? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/392025/erro-no-sql-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-this-is-incompat

Answer (score 6):

Tal como o erro indica, a instrução `SELECT` contém colunas não fazem parte da cláusula `GROUP BY` e ao mesmo tempo não estão agregadas (através de uma função de agregação).

A cláusula de agregação GROUP BY, quando aplicada a uma query, divide o conjunto de resultados em grupos, de acordo com as colunas indicadas, com o objectivo de aplicar uma ou mais (funções de) agregações a cada um dos grupos. Quando usada a instrução `GROUP BY`, o `SELECT` irá devolver apenas uma linha de resultado para cada um dos grupos.

Atendendo à definição e ao seu exemplo, estamos perante um problema:

Na sua tabela `occupation`, existe mais do que um `Name` para cada `occupation`. Ao não aplicar uma função de agregação na coluna `Name`, mas estando esta incluída na lista do `SELECT`, o SGBD não consegue determinar qual informação mostrar para cada uma das `occupation`, por exemplo, qual deveria ser o `Name` associado a Professor (na sua tabela existe mais do que uma possibilidade).

Para corrigir o erro, ou remove a coluna `Name` da instrução de `SELECT` (coisa que não faz muito sentido, pois seria o mesmo que um `SELECT DISTINCT` ou aplica-lhe uma função de agregação, por exemplo, `COUNT`.

```
SELECT occupation,
       COUNT(name) 
  FROM OCCUPATIONS 
 GROUP BY occupation;
```

A instrução anterior devolve o seguinte resultado:

```
Doctor, N1 
Professor, N2  
Singer, N3 
Actor N4
```

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro bruno, agradeço muito pela sua resposta =), a pergunta parece ser bem idiota agora depois dos esclarecimentos rsrs :´(

Comment: @bruno consegue me ajudar com esse erro? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/392025/erro-no-sql-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-this-is-incompat

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a instrução **DISTINCT**. Ela funciona basicamente como um **GROUP BY** de todos os campos, eliminando registros duplicados, mas, sem necessidade de alguma função de agregação, como é seu caso.