# Em MySQL agrupar por semana não lista corretamente

Tags: mysql

Tenho em MySQL a tabela `acesso`, que grava todos os acessos do cliente a um sistema, ela salva o id do usuário (`id_usuario`) e o dia (`dia`) do acesso. Estou fazendo uma consulta para checar os acessos semanais, assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(id_usuario) AS total, dia FROM acesso
GROUP BY WEEK(dia, 1)
ORDER BY dia ASC
```

O problema é que ele me retorna dias estranhos, alguns começam na segunda, outros na terça e muitas vezes alguns dias se repetem, veja um exemplo de um retorno:

```
02/01/2019 - 08/01/2019 - 130 acessos (02/01 = quarta | 08/01 = terça)
07/01/2019 - 13/01/2019 - 165 acessos (07/01 = segunda | 13/01 = domingo)
14/01/2019 - 20/01/2019 - 163 acessos (14/01 = segunda | 20/01 = domingo)
```

Reparem que no segundo resultado está até voltando um dia.

Como fazer essa consulta listar certinho as semanas? Pois precisaria de um resultado assim (intervalo entre domingo a sábado):

```
domingo - sábado = x acessos
domingo - sábado = x acessos
domingo - sábado = x acessos
```

A mudança de ano ou mês não importa. Acredito que em muitos dias não teria nenhum acesso, isso pode ser um problema para gerar dessa forma?

Comment: Da forma que agrupou é normal que não comecem e terminem sempre no mesmo dia. Tem certeza que é a função WEEK mesmo que precisa? E tem certeza que é o Modo 1 o melhor para o seu caso (atenção à "virada de ano" neste caso) - Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e por um exemplo do que esperava como saída.

Comment: @Bacco então, existe outra forma de agrupar que não seja por WEEK?

Comment: Depende do resultado que quer obter. Falta deixar claro na pergunta o critério desejado. Exemplos ajudam. Por exemplo, dividir o número sequencial do dia por 7, agrupa por semanas. TALVEZ o WEEK seja bom, mas ai depende do critério da virada do ano. Se o ano começa numa terça, o que faz? (que provavelmente vai confundir seus resultados com WEEK)

Comment: Editei! Mas realmente não me importa a mudança de ano ou mês, preciso só pegar o intervalo de domingo a sábado.

Comment: O segundo parâmetro de função `WEEK(dia, 1)` está informando que as semanas pesquisadas na consulta começam sempre na segunda-feira. Faça `WEEK(dia, 0)` para que as semanas consultadas tenham domingo como dia inicial.

Comment: @AugustoVasques ainda assim ele terá problema agrupando coisas de anos diferentes, e dependendo de onde cairá o fim do ano, vai "separar" a virada do ano indevidamente. O parâmetro "modo" é um pouco mais complexo do que só ajuste do dia inicial.

Comment: @Bacco eu iria recomendar ao usuário sua resposta neste momento. Pois concordo integralmente com você sobre os problemas com os casos de uso da função `WEEK()` e a maneira que abordou resolve o problema do usuário sem criar efeitos colaterais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer juntar apenas pela semana, de segunda a sexta, provavelmente este é um melhor caminho:

```
SELECT COUNT(id_usuario) AS total, dia FROM acesso
GROUP BY FLOOR(TO_DAYS(dia)/7)
ORDER BY dia
```

Se precisar mudar o dia de início da semana, pode usar um *offset*:

```
GROUP BY FLOOR((TO_DAYS(dia)+2)/7)
```

no lugar do `2` do exemplo você pode ajustar conforme desejado.

O `TO_DAYS` converte as datas em dias corridos desde o "Ano zero", e ao dividirmos por 7 fazemos com que os dias da mesma semana retornem o mesmo valor.

Foi evitado o uso do `WEEK()` por dois motivos:

- O tratamento dos dias na virada do ano pode ser um pouco confuso, visto que o `WEEK` tem modos de operação não tão claros para quem não está acostumado com o conceito de "semana do ano", comum em lugares como os EUA, por exemplo, mas não no Brasil;
- como ele "reseta" na virada do ano, agruparia coisas de anos diferentes, o que não seria desejável neste caso. Ainda, separaria de maneira indevida ocorrências entre um ano e outro que seriam da mesma semana.

Comment: Fucnionou! Mas agora tive outro problema, que talvez seja legal abrir outro post. Em semans que não tenho acesso, eu teria que receber 0, mas ele simplesmente ignora. Isso muda muito a situação, certo?

Comment: Isso é um problema clássico de SQL que tem dezenas de perguntas no site. O SQL só retorna o que existe, ele não tem um conceito de "grupo vazio" (afinal, só você é que sabe o conceito do grupo, não o SQL). Provavelmente o que seria melhor no seu caso seria tratar isso na exibição, numa linguagem cliente. Simplificando: o problema acontece mesmo sem o GROUP, imagine uma tabela simples com 2 colunas, uma sendo o numero do mes e a outra sendo "quantidade de vendas", sendo que o valor zero nao é lançado, somente de 1 pra cima, e vc precisa de um SELECT dos 12 meses.

Comment: Entendi, só levei isso em consideração no final do projeto, vou estudar isso e se realmente não conseguir volto aqui. Muito obrigado, aprendi bastante!

Comment: Para solucionar, tem N maneiras, e qual a melhor, só depende do caso. Quase sempre um loop mes a mes mostrando os resultados fora do SQL é melhor, mas se precisar mesmo resolver em SQL puro, precisa "gerar" os grupos de uma forma, mas é algo meio "feio" em MySQL (que não tem generators). Algo como SELECT 1 UNION 2 UNION 3 UNION 4 ... UNION 12 AS meses LEFT JOIN (sua query)

Comment: @Bacco por favor preciso muito de sua ajuda, da uma olhada POR FAVOR https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/392025/erro-no-sql-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-this-is-incompat

Comment: @Tiago a solução é o que está nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259973/70 - basicamente você está misturando colunas com e sem agregação, e isto não é aceito por padrão em versões mais novas do DB.

Comment: Olá @Bacco, o problema é que não foi eu quem fez esse select, foi um amigo que não esta mais presente. Esse select esta acima do meu conhecimento. Veja como ele funcionava http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28638/9

Comment: Foi o que eu falei e o que está na resposta, se não fizer agregação em todas as colunas ou mudar a configuração do DB, vai continuar com erro.

Comment: @Bacco se eu soubesse como fazer não estaria implorando ajuda. Já desativo o `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` não retorna nenhum valor https://prnt.sc/o3wmip

Comment: @Bacco Me ajuda, por favor, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/392025/left-join-group-by-this-is-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by

Comment: @Tiago implorar ajuda não faz parte do escopo do site. Se você tem um dúvida específica nova faça uma que pode ser respondida em nova pergunta, caso contrário se já tem uma resposta ela é duplicata e não pode mais ser feita. Se só quer uma ajuda geral e não específica não faz parte do escopo do site. Fazer um código para pessoas quem não sabem fazer não faz parte do escopo do site. Você precisa entender minimamente o que faz. Você deve aprender a programar, fazer, e se tiver uma dúvida específica postar em pergunta. O que está fazendo aqui é errado e pode ser considerado comportamento abusivo.