# LEFT JOIN. GROUP BY. this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho um sistema que usava em 2013. Estou migrando para a versão mais recente do php e estou tendo esse erro:

> Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sitepara_bd.financ_despesa.data' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

**EXEMPLO DA ÉPOCA:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28638/17

Código:

```
$year = $_GET["ano"]; //2013
$query_rs = "SELECT
     $year AS Year,
     m.month AS Month,
     fr.SomaEntradaAtual AS Entry,
     fd.SomaSaidaAtual AS Output,
     IFNULL(fr.SomaEntradaAtual,0) - IFNULL(fd.SomaSaidaAtual,0) AS Balance
 FROM (
       SELECT 'Jan' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Feb' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Mar' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Apr' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'May' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Jun' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Jul' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Aug' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Sep' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Oct' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Nov' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Dec' AS MONTH
      ) AS m
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT Month(DATA) AS rmonth, SUM(valor) AS SomaEntradaAtual,
    DATA FROM financ_receita WHERE YEAR(DATA) = $year
    GROUP BY MONTH(DATA)) AS fr
ON MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(m.month, ' $year'),'%M %Y')) = MONTH(fr.DATA)
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT Month(DATA) AS dmonth, SUM(valor) AS SomaSaidaAtual,
       DATA FROM financ_despesa WHERE YEAR(DATA) = $year
       GROUP BY MONTH(DATA)) AS fd
ON MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(m.month, ' $year'),'%M %Y')) = MONTH(fd.DATA)";
```

**Por ser um select acima do meu conhecimento, havia pedido ajuda. Agora novamente pedir ajuda para acertar esse erro.**

Li em alguns lugares dizendo para desativar o `only_full_group_by`, mas fazendo isso não retorna nenhum valor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Comment: Em seus subselects você coloca o campo DATA na lista de campos a recuperar mas tal campo não consta da lista do GROUP BY. Versões antigas do MySQL aceitavam tal construção mas as versões mais recentes podem não aceitá-la. É o seu caso em que seu SGBD está configurado com a opção: sql_mode=only_full_group_by. Se quiser o mesmo comportamento anterior não especifique tal cláusula já que ela não é DEFAULT na versão 8.

Comment: @anonimo como meu código deve ficar não sei como modifica-lo, pois quem me ajudou na época foi uma amigo. Ele não esta mais presente. Eu já havia desativado o `only_full_group_by`, mas quando faço não aparece nenhum resultado na tabela.

Comment: Veja: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @anonimo por favor, me ajude no meu código estou desde cedo tentando fazer isso funcionar. Só falta essa parte.

Comment: A solução eu já disse acima, utilize o sql_mode adequado, mas a alternativa é você retirar o campo DATA das select-lists em seus subselects.

Comment: Mas eu preciso agupar as datas.

Comment: Então acrescente o campo DATA à lista da cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: @anonimo, mas se eu soubesse fazer isso já teria :( como é um código complexo, estou perdido. Ele é acima do meu conhecimento, todos os outros selects que tenho são simples, apenas esse é complexo.

Comment: @anonimo, por favor, me de essa força. Não to sabendo fazer isso.

Comment: @Tiago, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28638/20

Comment: @bruno muito obrigado. Posta aqui sua resposta para eu dar pontuação. Muito, mas muito obrigado!!!! Vendo o resultado, consigo perceber qual é a forma correta, muito obrigado por sua gentileza!

Comment: @Bruno voltei para o desenvolvimento, e esta aparecendo essa mensagem de erro no phpMyAdmin (https://prnt.sc/o6k8ic), esse é o novo link (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad487c/1). Consegue me ajudar novamente?